# UILoader cover background in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, background, actionscript, uiloader

I'm using ActionScript 3 and the UILoader component to show a .jpg image.

I would like a "covered background" result, like the css property :

```
background-size : cover;
```

I tested the parameter scaleContent (true or false):

```
uilBackground.scaleContent = true;
```

But the result is not a true "covered background".

I think to set the scaleContent false and made a ratio calcul to modify the size of the UILoader component.

Is it a good way ? Are there others solutions ?

Thanks. 
Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Alsacrations jQuery solution (http://www.alsacreations.com/astuce/lire/1216-arriere-plan-background-extensible.html) :

```
function backgroundCover(){
    var image_width:Number = uilBackground.content.width;
    var image_height:Number = uilBackground.content.height;

    var over = image_width / image_height; 
    var under = image_height / image_width; 

    var body_width = uilBackground.width; 
    var body_height = uilBackground.height; 

    if (body_width / body_height >= over) { 

        uilBackground.content.width = body_width;
        uilBackground.content.height = Math.ceil(under * body_width);
        uilBackground.move(0,(Math.abs((under * body_width) - body_height) / -2));

    }else{
        uilBackground.content.width = Math.ceil(over * body_height);
        uilBackground.content.height = body_height;
        uilBackground.move((Math.abs((over * body_height) - body_width) / -2),0);
    }

    //trace(uilBackground.content.width);
    //trace(uilBackground.content.height);  
}
```

It seems work.